# Set up Bugzilla on IIS 10 with FastCGI

Tags: iis, fastcgi, perl, cgi, bugzilla

I'm a bit of an IIS noob so apologies if this is vague. I've successfully set up Bugzilla on IIS 10 but it's pretty slow - a few seconds to load each page even on the same local machine. As I understand it I need to use FastCGI to fix this.

I basically have no idea how to switch the `.cgi` and `.pl` mappings to FastCGI. Anything I try just shows an error page after making changes (typically just a generic "500 internal server error" referencing FastCGI).

I think it's losing the command line arguments to `perl.exe` when handling a request. But I'm guessing. I'm using Strawberry Perl if it makes a difference.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might get betters Windows-focused answers on [SU].

Comment: "As I understand it I need to use FastCGI to fix this."

From where do you understand this? It's not mentioned AFAICS in the Bugzilla install instructions...